# Html/Css/Js: Display text before <i> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, legend

This is a rather simple question, but i cant get to the right solution.
I am working on a legend for my leaflet map, I got this far:

[image: Screenshot of the legend]

However I would like to display **the 0 before** the color block and only **the 4 afer the color block.**
I am creating the colors with i-tags. The whole JS code looks like this:

```
function getColor(d) 
            {
              return   d > 4  ?  '#045a8d' : //4
                       d > 3  ?  '#2b8cbe' : //3
                       d > 2  ?  '#74a9cf' : //2
                       d > 1  ?  '#bdc9e1' : //1
                                  '#f1eef6';
}
    ...

    grades = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

...


div.innerHTML += '0 ';


     for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
      div.innerHTML += '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' + (!grades[i + 1] ? grades[i] : '');}
```

CSS:

```
.legend {
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555;
}
.legend i {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Any suggestions, on how I can display the 0 before the colors? I bet its quite easy, but all I tried didnt work so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0tLoL5v2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the i's are floating left they are moving the 0 over to the right. If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/73k05k7u/ I have put the 0 and 1 into a span and floated them left as well. So now it all displays inline. I also took the call to add the 4 out of the loop as you can just do it when the loop has completed. Makes it a little more readable and less comparisons required. NB best practise you should build up a string and set the innerHTML property just once.

```
// CSS
.legend span{
    float:left;

}

// JS
div.innerHTML += '<span>0 </span>';


 for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
  div.innerHTML += '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ';     
 }
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML +  '<span>' +  (grades.length -1)+  '</span>';
```